# Reading files in Linq's SelectMany() throws System.IO.IOException when ran without ToList()

Tags: c#, linq, io

I am curious as to why the following piece of codes fails with a System.IO.IOException, saying that the process can't access the file cause it is being used by another process.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const string filename = "tmp.txt";
        File.AppendAllText(filename, "x");
        var output = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).SelectMany(_ => File.ReadAllLines(filename));
        File.WriteAllLines(filename, output);
    }
}
```

By simply throwing a `ToList()` on the end of the Linq Pipeline, I avoid this problem, but I haven't been able to figure out why this is the case.

Comment: you have to first create a file on file system, write data on it and then need to read from there.

Comment: `.ToList()` as well as `.ToArray()` *materializes* the result: you have a collection in memory and no file opened; *Linq* is lazy: if you don't have `.ToList()`; `output` start executing on `WriteAllLines` only (when Linq *has to read*) and you have conflict: `File.WriteAllLines` wants to **write** while `var output = .. ` should **read**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You see the effect of Linq *laziness* and *materialization*.

With `.ToList()` added we have the `output` *materialized*: *Linq* executes the query (*open* file, fill the collection and *close* the file):

```
 // List<T> collection
 var output = Enumerable
   .Range(0, 10)
   .SelectMany(_ => File.ReadAllLines(filename))
   .ToList();  // <- We want a collection in memory
```

So when it's time to write, we write the data from memory do disk

```
 // Writing down the collection
 File.WriteAllLines(filename, output);
```

Without `.ToList()` Linq (being *lazy*) does *nothing*:

```
 // IEnumerable<T> 
 var output = Enumerable
   .Range(0, 10)
   .SelectMany(_ => File.ReadAllLines(filename)); // <- No more than a declaration
```

When it's time to write

```
 File.WriteAllLines(filename, output);
```

*Linq* finds out that it has to provide the data that should be written - `output` and starts doing this: it tries to *open file* but fails in this operation since the file has been opened with `File.WriteAllLines`.

Comment: Much more eloquent than my jumbled terminology

Comment: Aaaah, of course! Thanks a lot! What confused me was that the IOException was thrown from the File.ReadAllLines, but I guess it makes sense, since the ReadAllLines isn't executed until after the WriteAllLines prompts it for an answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Because you are trying to read and write to the same file simultaneously,

`ToList()` causes the execution (enumeration) to happen at that point, where the SelectMany returns an `IEnumerable` and waits until its executed (enumerated) at `File.WriteAllLines(filename, output)`